# Multiprocessing return objects created by process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I am using multiprocessing lib for accelerating process of class creation. Minimal example of my code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
class Custom_Class(FigureCanvas)
    .
    .
    .

def generate_class_func(list_of_dfs, arg1, arg2):
    list_of_custom_classes = list()
    for df in list_of_dfs:
        custom_class = Custom_Class(df, arg1, arg2)
        list_of_custom_classes.append(custom_class)
    return list_of_custom_classes

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    with mp.Pool() as p:
        list_of_classes_list = p.starmap(generate_class_func, zip(list_of_dfs, repeat(arg1), repeat(arg2)))
        p.close()
        p.join()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I got `multiprocess.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: ... Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'Custom_Class' object")'` error. I also tried pathos.ProcessingPool module but the error is same. How can I return custom objects with multiprocessing?

Comment: You might start by reading the pickle module's documentation to understand how to make an object serializable.

Comment: To be clear: To pass an object between processes (the whole point of `multiprocessing`), you need to be able to serialize it into some kind of form that can be sent between those processes. Pickle isn't the only serialization form, but it's maybe the easiest one to comply with -- getting things to/from JSON or msgpack, f/e, is more work.

Comment: ...in general, you're not going to succeed at passing something like a qt canvas object between processes; state like the connection to the display server / window manager / &c used by qt isn't serializable by nature. Build an object that just stores your data, generate _that_ in your subprocesses, and then transform them to canvas objects back in the main process.

Comment: As an aside, to pass an object from the subprocess back to the parent means that the object needs to be serialized on one end and recreated on the other. This is only worthwhile if the original object creation in the process is much slower than its recreation in the parent.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, problem is much clear now.  I am having trouble generating matplotlib plots from a big dataset since it takes time to plot all rows and show them on qt, so wanted to divide plotting into subprocesses. Honestly, I am not a CS expert and looking for a possible approach to deal with it. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Generating the data for the plots is fine, but the plot itself is a GUI, which will have big problems being passed to a different process. This may be an instance where you can have a shared dataset via something like `multiprocessing.shared_memory`, and then use MVVM to generate views of the data in the main process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of `dill` and `multiprocess`. One easy trick to make thing more serializable is to use `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing`.  The former is a fork of the latter that uses `dill` instead of `pickle`, so you immediately get the ability to serialize more objects, including most custom classes.

```
>>> from matplotlib.pylab import FigureCanvasBase
>>> class Custom_Class(FigureCanvasBase):
...   def __init__(self, df, arg1, arg2):
...     super().__init__()
...     self.df = df
...     self.arg1 = arg1
...     self.arg2 = arg2
... 
>>> def generate_class_func(list_of_dfs, arg1, arg2):
...     list_of_custom_classes = list()
...     for df in list_of_dfs:
...         custom_class = Custom_Class(df, arg1, arg2)
...         list_of_custom_classes.append(custom_class)
...     return list_of_custom_classes
... 
>>> 
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> with mp.Pool() as p:
...   from itertools import repeat
...   list_of_classes_list = p.starmap(generate_class_func, zip([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]], repeat('arg1'), repeat('arg2')))
...   p.close()
...   p.join()
... 
>>> list_of_classes_list
[[<__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b35a390>, <__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b0fcb10>], [<__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b373110>, <__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11ae1fa10>], [<__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b37b990>, <__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b3965d0>], [<__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11b114f90>, <__main__.Custom_Class object at 0x11adfdb90>]]
```

Comment: This guy pickles, and dill is absolutely better in every way so thanks Mike! In my experience with multiprocessing you should make every effort to avoid having to serialize classes in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your contributions to python, appreciated. As far as I understood there is no way to serialize FigureCanvas class right? Because it works on FigureCanvasBase but not FigureCanvas.

Comment: If `dill` can't serialize a `FigureCanvas` class, then the answer is probably no, not easily.  You can, potentially, build a custom class that includes a `__reduce__` method (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) to inform the serializer how to serialize the class.

Comment: I see, it looks like it needs more effort than I expected. Thanks again Mike for your clear answer!